# Loading animation on edit screen is stretched vertically and appears as vertical lines

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, edits, images

I was suggesting an edit (on Android.SE) when I noticed that the loading GIF animation next to the Edit button was stretched vertically. It’s this `alax-loader` image:

[image: The <code>img.ajax-loader</code> element has a size of 18 × 37.8]

Its height appears too large, as it looks closer to vertical black lines `|||` instead of black dots `...`.

The rest of the loading symbols on the site look normal (`...`).

Comment: I noticed this, too. Not sure whether that’s a bug, though. The source for the “AJAX dots” is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/progress-dots.gif`, the `<img>`’s class name is `ajax-loader`. It’s not reproducible everywhere.

Comment: I thought this was intentional.

Comment: Flex layout is fun, but when you turn it on for a container without remembering that an image gets inserted there later on... https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvmuW.png

Comment: This issue has just been reported again on MSO: [Why does editing an answer on Stack Overflow always put funny black lines beside it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376234/4642212).

Comment: @Aaron was the fix rolled back somehow? See above comment.